# How to manage pages tree in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

i am building a site, with few models with relations and a lot of static pages. How I can manage static pages hierarchy in Active Admin or rails_admin? Please advice how I can set up CMS functionality with this tools. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I use rails_admin build a simple CMS site. the requirement is similar with yours.

suggest you build a model Menu or Category, you can make Menu as a tree.

try [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set)

rails_admin are friendly with [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor), with paperclip or carriarwave, you can let page insert image convniently. for these features what you should do is only edit the rails_admin.rb

for active_admin, it is too slow in development mode.